# Python: Replace() takes no effect on write to file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm working on a web parser for a webpage containing mathematical constants. I need to replace some characters in order to have it on a specific format, but I dont know why if I print it, i seems to be working fine; but when I open the output file the format achieved by replace() doesn't seems to have took effect.

That's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/constants/ConstantsOfPhysicsAndMath.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read(), "html5lib")
f = open("ebyteParse-output.txt", "w")

table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "grid9"})

rows = table.findAll("tr")
for tr in rows:
    # If its a category of constants we write that as a comment
    if tr.has_attr("bgcolor"):
        f.write("\n\n# " + tr.find(text=True) + "\n")
        continue

    cols = tr.findAll("td")
    if (len(cols) >= 2):
        if (cols[0]["class"][0] == "box" or cols[0]["class"][0] == "boxi" and cols[1]["class"][0] == "boxa"):
            constant = str(cols[0].find(text=True)).replace(" ", "-")
            value = str(cols[1].find(text=True))
            value = value.replace(" ", "").replace("...", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
            print(constant + "\t" + value)
            f.write(constant + "\t" + value)

    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

That is what print shows:

[image]

That is what I get on the output file

[image]

Thanks you,
Salva

Comment: A variable can't change its value between the `print` and `f.write` lines. I suspect you're looking at the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

File i was looking for was catched so no changes where seen. Thanks for answering